# Cannot match the parameter list for MessageBox::Show

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli

I'm attempting to display the Error message denoted by the code given to me by GetLastError() and formatted by FormatMessage() within a MessageBox. (Using C++/CLI)
However for some reason I just can't match the argument list of MessageBox::Show.
I'm attempting to replicate a solution provided by Doron Moraz in this forum thread:
  http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?478858-GetLastError()-in-a-MessageBox()

However when I attempt to compile my code I get:

```
'System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show' : none of the 21 overloads could convert all the argument types
1>          c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll: could be 'System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show(System::String ^,System::String ^,System::Windows::Forms::MessageBoxButtons,System::Windows::Forms::MessageBoxIcon)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll: or       'System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show(System::Windows::Forms::IWin32Window ^,System::String ^,System::String ^,System::Windows::Forms::MessageBoxButtons)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(int, LPCTSTR, const wchar_t [6], long)'
```

As you can see below my code is fairly similar to the solution provided at the link. only I get the above error. The question is, Why? (see my code below).

```
if((m_hglrc = wglCreateContext(m_hDC)) == NULL)//if the creation of a wgl context fails
                {
                    MessageBox::Show("wglCreateContext Failed");//let us know

                    void* lpBuffer; //create a buffer to hold our error message

                        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER|FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,               // It´s a system error
                        NULL,                                      // No string to be formatted needed
                        ::GetLastError(),                               // Hey Windows: Please explain this error!
                        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL,SUBLANG_DEFAULT),  // Do it in the standard language
                        (LPTSTR)&lpBuffer,                                 // Put the message here
                        0,                     // Number of bytes to store the message
                        NULL);

                    System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show( NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpBuffer, _T("Error"),MB_OK|MB_ICONWARNING);

                    // Free the buffer.
                    if(lpBuffer)LocalFree(lpBuffer);


                    return 0;
                }
```

In case it's relevant, my includes are:

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include<tchar.h>

using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
```

Thanks in advance,
Guy

Comment: MessageBox( NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpBuffer, __T("LastRrror"), MB_OK );

Comment: you need to use this LPCSTR stuff,  bleee

Comment: I;ve tried changing from MessageBox::Show() to just MessageBox(), and I get:
"error C2872: 'MessageBox' : ambiguous symbol
1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winuser.h(7535) : int MessageBox(HWND,LPCTSTR,LPCTSTR,UINT)'
1>          or       'c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox'"

Comment: I'm guessing that that's to do with a conflict between two different kinds of MessageBox through the various libraries ive included?

Comment: just type MessageBo... you will see what to use and its arguments

Comment: Cool, after some research on string theory (excuse the pun) done [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2995/The-Complete-Guide-to-C-Strings-Part-I-Win32-Chara) & searching the intellisense, I've found that MessageBoxW compiled for me. 
Leading to the next problem (marshalling). But that's a new question  altogether :)
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've solved this by switching to the unmanaged API, but here's how you'd use the managed one.

If you're going to use the a managed API, you'll want to use managed objects. In your call to MessageBox::Show, you have several unmanaged objects. According to the error message, it interpreted your parameters like this:

```
MessageBox::Show( NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpBuffer, _T("Error"),MB_OK|MB_ICONWARNING);
// seen by compiler as: int, LPCTSTR, const wchar_t [6], long
```

Here's the method I think you're trying to call in the MessageBox class:

```
Show(IWin32Window^ owner, String^ text, String^ caption, 
    MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon)
```

- `NULL` is generally #defined as `0`, which is an integer. To produce a proper null pointer in C++/CLI, you want to use `nullptr`.
- Both lpBuffer and "Error" need to be managed string objects.

  - For lpBuffer, you can just do `gcnew String(lpBuffer)`, and it'll invoke the proper constructor (the one that takes a [wide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y4za026.aspx) or [narrow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9s9t975.aspx) character pointer).
  - For "Error", just remove the `_T()`. The compiler will figure out that you want a managed string object and will provide one containing "Error".
- In the managed API, the buttons & icon are contained in separate enums. You're referencing the unmanaged integer values here. You'll want to replace this with separate parameters for [MessageBoxButtons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons.aspx) and [MessageBoxIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxicon.aspx).

Once all that is done, here's the final call:

```
MessageBox::Show(nullptr, gcnew String(lpBuffer), "Error", 
    MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Warning);
```

However, we can do a little better: If you're not going to pass in a owner window, don't call the [API that has a owner window parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bywy47k3.aspx), call the [API that doesn't](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/365dky5y.aspx).

```
MessageBox::Show(gcnew String(lpBuffer), "Error", 
    MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Warning);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I went back and gave it a go and it worked for me. I also had to change lpBuffer from type `void*` to `char*` as string couldnt convert between the two.